# Spring boot not logging CQL queries

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, cassandra

I am using `Spring Boot Data Cassandra` in my spring boot project, I am trying to log CQL queries but setting `spring.jpa.show-sql` to `true` is not working.
here is my application.properties

```
spring.data.cassandra.keyspace-name=sample
spring.data.cassandra.contact-points=127.0.0.1
spring.data.cassandra.port=9042
spring.data.cassandra.schema-action=CREATE_IF_NOT_EXISTS
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible using a LatencyTracker

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    public Application(Cluster cluster) {
        this.cluster = cluster;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {

    cluster.register(new LatencyTracker() {
                @Override
                public void update(Host host, Statement statement, Exception exception, long newLatencyNanos) {
                    System.out.println(statement);
                }

                @Override
                public void onRegister(Cluster cluster) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onUnregister(Cluster cluster) {

                }
            });
    }

}
```

Comment: My application fails to start with "org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate."

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what are you expecting from a **JPA** property.

According to the current boot [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html), there is no such property which can show you the executed queries.

However, you can go with the native logging implementation explained [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/2.1/manual/logging/#logging-query-latencies).